# Abundant substances which I may use like coupling agents

Tags: polymers

What is the most abundant substances which I may use like coupling agent for Wood plastic composite with HDPE polymer? I don't want maleated polyolefin because they are not so abundant in my country.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don'y want to use maleated polyolefin (the best coupling agent for this composite), you can use oxidized polyethylene, ethylene propylene rubber, ethylene-co-glycidyl methacrylate or polyolefin elastomer.